# Is it okay to rely on MIME TYPE when verifying using JavaScript if the file uploaded is of audio, video or image type?

Tags: javascript, mime-types, file-type

I know that from security standpoint this is not safe. But I intend to use the javascript code for convenience. So just as a first pass.
My goal is to avoid any false-positives i.e. it is fine if a malicious hacker manipulated the file to have the mime-types that I accept (because I will be doing a second pass on server side) but I I would want to prevent legal files being detected as problematic.

**UPDATE**

Prototype of a working solution http://jsfiddle.net/tankchintan/5EUjE/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is OK so long as you are confirming the type on the server side.

Using it on the client will just be a convenience to the end user. How are you determining the mime type? If it is just on extension, then you may as well just check for a valid extension on the client side.

#### Update

It appears to be just mapping extensions to file types, as a `png` renamed as `mp3` is `mpeg/audio` to the code.

So, ensure you validate the type on the server by checking the file's contents, not its extension.

Comment: I am determining the mimetype using javascript to get access to the file being uploaded & then using the "type" attribute of the object. Kind of like FieldName.files.0.type. so I am verifying if that value has "video" or "audio" in it.

Comment: @Chantz interesting, I've never seen that method before. Can you show some code?

Comment: @Chantz nice, thanks! File uploads have a `type` attribute? Didn't know that.

Comment: @Chantz Very interesting. However, I renamed a `png` file to `mp3` and it passed. Maybe it internally is just mapping extensions to mime types.

Comment: @alex, yeah that's what I was not sure about.  But since this is a first pass & a convenient GUI I thought it can do as long as it does not give false-positives.